# static struct in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, initialization, static-initialization

that this snippet of code actually do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void test();

namespace {
    static struct StaticStruct {
        StaticStruct() { 
            test(); 
        }
    } TheStaticSupport;
}


int main(void) {



    return 0;
}


void test() {
    printf("testing function\n");
}
```

why does the test function actually get called? and why use the "anonymous" namespace? I found this piece of code in an open source project...

Comment: `void teste();` ... `test();`.  I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
static struct StaticStruct {
    StaticStruct() { 
        test(); 
    }
} TheStaticSupport;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
struct StaticStruct {
    StaticStruct() { 
        test(); 
    }
};

static StaticStruct TheStaticSupport;
```

It defines a type named `StaticStruct` and an instance of the type named `TheStaticSupport` with internal linkage (though, since it is declared in an unnamed namespace, the `static` is redundant).

The constructor for `TheStaticSupport` is called before `main()` is entered, to construct the object.  This calls the `test()` function.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous namespace gives the contained objects internal linkage, as their fully qualified name can never be known to anyone outside the translation unit. It's the sophisticated man's version of the old `static` in C.

Note that you do declare a global object of type `StaticStruct`, and *its* constructor (which runs before `main()` is called) calls `test()`.

Comment: Technically, entities in an unnamed namespace may have external linkage.